# Business Rules Engine

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, alert, business-rules

I have a SQL server database on an Azure VM. The database's records table is updated by reading from sensors. What I want is to make a simple business rules engine where I can generate alerts and create new table entries in another table based on the real-time value my database has just received.
So, I need something which is always on and performs a check on every new entry in the database and act accordingly.e.g. 
if([temperature]<30 || [temperature]>40)
{
  1.call an API (already developed. Sends a text message to a specific cell number)
  2. creates a new entry in the database table "alerts" 
}

What tool/technology should I use for it? I've never done anything of the sort! Never even written a script or a stored procedure :|

Note: I'll need to the same thing for my Analysis Services OLAP cube in the future.

Comment: "based on the real-time value my database has just received" So you have an existing mechanism inserting data into a table in your database and you want to run some process every time that data is inserted?  Sounds like a good candidate for an Insert Trigger to me.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Okay, what's an insert trigger and where in the SQL server management studio can I create it?

Comment: Never mind. Googled it! :D Thank you!

Comment: You should be aware that triggers run synchronously within the connection and transaction that is trying to modify their table.  This means that they will stall the writing process until they complete. And any unhandled errors in the trigger will cause the write to be rolled-back and cancelled.  You might be better to use the trigger to just copy the new records to a Service Broker queue or some other place where they can be handled asynchonuosly and outside of your real-time writers.